# Can you use Polygon Mumbai Testnet in production?

Tags: testnets, polygon

I am currently working on a Dapp that only needs to utilise the blockchain as an immutable database to sign transactions to confirm its the correct person/wallet performing an action.

Would it be possible to avoid gas fees by using a test net in production and if not what are the reasons this wouldn't work or would be ill advised? As I have currently deployed with no issues. For my apps purpose it doesn't seem necessary to to upgrade to the main net but my experience is limited in this field.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact is that testnets are not `decentralized` enough, it is easier to take control of a testnet.
Nobody does it because it's not worth it, but if tomorrow a protocol decides to deploy on a testnet, and the TVL is worth a few million $, it will require less than the TVL to take control of the testnet.

A system is considered secure if the resources used to hack it are more expensive than the benefit of the hack.

> Example: If I need $ 1,000,000 (machines, zombies, tools,
> computations, etc.) to be able to hack a system that will only be
> profitable for 50,000$. It means that my system is well secured.

It's up to you to measure the risk, depending on your smart contract and its usefulness, but technically it's possible

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Appreciate the insight into the security concerns regarding testnets. Luckily this is just a final year project so in terms of value there is nothing to be lost but the points you made would be perfect for picking up extra marks for research. Thanks for the quality explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

I would not worry about deploying to a test net such as Mumbai. From what it seems, your project is for testing purposes only and will not be of use to hackers.

I used the Mumbai test net for a project yesterday, and it was for a coding course. I submitted my deployed contract to their dapp, and they actually keep a record of all Ethereum addresses on Mumbai so that they can airdrop NFTs to students later. I thought I should add this because it seems very similar to what you are trying to accomplish because they had to verify that my address what was deployed the contract.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. sorry was out and only got back to this now. My project is purely for a final year project so wanted to avoid fees even though they are rather minimal on the polygon network. Adam gave some good insight down below, the testnet will work like you said but with his explanation I feel it might be worth to use the mainnet and grab some extra marks with his reasoning :)